# Windows API Timer Queues and thread safety question

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, winapi, timer, synchronization

Basically, my application uses [Windows timer queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/timer-queues) to create a timer that will be invoked every 50 milliseconds using `CreateTimerQueueTimer` (reference is below).

Here is a synopsis of the function that will be called when the timer is invoked:

```
// Set up the timer
CreateTimerQueueTimer(timerHandle, NULL, foo, NULL, 20, 20, WT_EXECUTEDEFAULT);
//…
//...
// Timer callback
void foo(void* param, BOOLEAN b)
{
    static bool doing_timer_func = false;
    if (!doing_timer_func) 
    {
        doing_timer_func = true;
        MyType *p = reinterpret_cast<MyType*>(param); 
        CallSomeFunction();  // This function may take more than 50 ms.
    }
    doing_timer_func = false;
}
```

My contention is that the following code (even though it is run as a single-thread application) is not safe in terms of guaranteeing that the `doing_timer_func` boolean will always prevent reentrancy issues. 
 Even though the `bool` seems to "do the job", in general, the code looks safe, but is it?

The `WM_EXECUTEDEFAULT` flag, according to the Windows documentation, will place the timer on a non I/O worker thread, so in essence the application is using multiple threads, even though the application is intended to be single-threaded.

Since the timers used here are synchronization objects, I have always had the notion that to guard against anything unexpected, an application should use proper synchronization primitives (mutex, critical section, SRWLocks, etc.), and not mere boolean variable(s).

Am I wrong here, and the code is really safe?

More Information:

> Compiler used -- Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: It is not safe, as two threads can get past the `if (!doing_timer_func)` check before either of them sets it to true.  You'll need to use either `std::atomic<bool>` or some form of double checked locking, but I don't know off the top of my head how well that is supported in VS2010.  Why aren't you using a newer version of the compiler?

Comment: With Windows, you have InterlockedXXX atomic operations available, like InterlockedCompareExchange : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-interlockedcompareexchange

Comment: Unfortunately, the company is using VS 2010.  But let's assume that the only entity calling `foo` is the timer proc.  Is this still safe?  My feeling is that it isn't.  @SimonMourier -- Yep, I know that there are atomic API functions in Windows, and may probably need to use them here.

Comment: simply use `static LONG active = FALSE; if (InterlockedExchange(&active, TRUE) == FALSE){... active = FALSE;}`

Comment: Easy to test if it will call you re-entrantly, put a `Sleep()` in the callback for a longer duration than the period of the timer, and see what happens.